# error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Ethernet.h':

Tags: ethernet

i'm trying to compile native code in VC++ using galileo sdk for windows iot. 
I've copied Ethernet.h file to the include directory of 
D:\galileo-sdk-develop\galileo-sdk-develop\source> but still getting error on cannot open include file "Ethernet.h"